# How to set initial value for dropdownlist while using sqldatasource as binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  2 `dropdownlist`, which are bound to a `SQLDataSource` and value of `2nd dropdownlist` is based on 1st `dropdownlist`.  The problem is that by default `dropdownlist` are displaying actual values.  I put initialvalue in dpsem so, it's working correctly.but when i do same in `dpsubj dropdownlist` it is showing previous value also.

If I select dpsem--4 then dpsubj should be A,B,C, and if if i select dpsem--6 then dpsubj should be D,E,F.  But it is displaying A,B,C,D,E,F...

I am knowing that it is problem related to Autopostback...

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="dpsem" runat="server" Height="28px" 
                   Width="99px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="selectsemester" 
                   DataTextField="sem_no" DataValueField="sem_no" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">-select</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>

     <asp:DropDownList ID="dpsubj" runat="server" Height="28px" 
                   Width="99px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Selectscode" 
                   DataTextField="scode" DataValueField="scode" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">-select</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Selectscode" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttendenceManagementConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [scode] FROM [Semester_Wise_Subject] WHERE (([branch_name] = @branch_name) AND ([sem_no] = @sem_no))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lbdept" DefaultValue="IT" Name="branch_name" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dpsem" DefaultValue="6" Name="sem_no" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>



    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="selectsemester" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttendenceManagementConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [sem_no] FROM [Batch_year]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: improve your question!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dpsubj.Items.Clear()`.. and then again load the filtered data on `selectedindexchanged` it will first delete all teh previous records in dpsubj dropdown and then use code to load value in dpsubj

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create a SelectedIndexChanged event on the first drop down and have that event cause a databind on the second drop down.  Also by default if you don't want the second drop down to display data get rid of the default parameter values.

If you are doing anything with ajax you also want to make sure that the first drop down updates the second in your script manager as well.

Answer (score 0):

set `AppendDataBoundItems="false"` on `dpsubj`

since you set this property as true, items are not cleared before data binding.